# Why evaluate test data in a loop in tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

A few models implemented in TensorFlow posted on [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) have their 'evaluation' function run a while loop, such as resnet (in [resnet_main.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/resnet/resnet_main.py)), etc.

I wonder why we need to evaluate the test data more than once.

Answer (score 1):

The test data is evaluated once: [the loop is on its samples](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/resnet/resnet_main.py#L143). The reason is rather mundane: when the test data is large, it cannot be processed as a whole because the whole network could not fit in memory. In that case, it is split in minibatches.

So even though training and testing loop on minibatches, the underlying reasons are indeed quite different.

**EDIT**

The *outer* loop has a different role: [a new model is loaded at each iteration](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/resnet/resnet_main.py#L139). This is used in case you run the evaluation in a different process that regularly reads the output of training on disk and evaluate them.

The rationale is explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn#evaluating_a_model): it is useful when you are working in an environment where you can have training and testing occurring on different GPUs.

Comment: I agree with splitting the dataset, but that is inside the while loop starting on line 130. It seems the loop is not gonna break unless FLAGS.eval_once is true.

Comment: Re: EDIT, that makes sense, but I don't see how the program detects whether there is a change of the checkpoint file between 2 while-loop iterations. If there is no change, then the program is evaluating the same dataset with the same parameters.

Comment: True. Then I suppose the [pause of a minute between each iteration](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/resnet/resnet_main.py#L172) has been chosen to maximize the chances that a new model is ready. If it is not, I suppose it is not such a big deal to occasionally make the same computation twice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't evaluate the test data more than once. You evaluate disjunct subsets of the test set in order to obtain the evaluation of the union of those subsets (that whole test set)

Comment: I agree, but there is a while loop starting on line 130. It seems the loop is not gonna break unless FLAGS.eval_once is true.

Comment: Because this code is used to evaluate to model every 60 seconds when that flag is not used. The evaluation is made using batches as wrote above